# How to use while loop in mysql (MariaDB)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, while-loop, mariadb, heidisql

I am trying to use while loop in my stored procedure, but it doesn't want to accept the syntax.
I am using HeidiSQL as a Studio, database is MySQL MariaDB.

```
BEGIN
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE taskTemp
SELECT jc.Id as JID
FROM jobs as j 
left join jobcards     as jc   on j.JobcardId = jc.Id
left join tasks        as t    on j.Id = t.JobId
left join assignments  as a    ON t.Id = a.TaskId
WHERE a.PerformerId = currentUserId
group by jc.Id;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(JID  SEPARATOR ',') AS result
INTO @test
FROM taskTemp;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE UserTasks
Select j.Id ,j.JobcardId as JcID, t.Id as TaskID ,js.Name as TaskStatus
from jobs                        as j 
left join tasks             as t on j.Id = t.JobId
     Join assignments       as a on t.Id = a.TaskId and a.PerformerId = currentUserId
left Join jobstatuses       as js on t.StatusId = js.Id
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(j.JobcardId, @test);

alter table UserTasks add UserStatus longtext;

SET @n=0;
SET @i=0;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UserTasks INTO @n;

WHILE (@n>0) DO
SET @n=@n-1;
END WHILE;


drop temporary table taskTemp;
drop temporary table UserTasks;
END
```

Above you can see my whole stored procedure, so the problem is coming at this row:

```
WHILE (@n>0) DO
SET @n=@n-1;
END WHILE;*
```

*

I have tried without brackets also @n>0, but also without success

Comment: what's the error ?

Comment: @Gosfly incorrect syntaxt near the while, when I remove the while block, everything is okay

Comment: Please provide the 1064 error message; the "near" part points exactly to the offending spot.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue with SQL mode configuration in your mariadb environment. You can try one of the following options :

**1. Use oracle loop syntax :**

```
SET @n=5;
WHILE @n>0 LOOP
    SET @n=@n-1;
    SELECT @n;
END LOOP;
```

**2. Change sql mode to tradionnal :**

```
SET sql_mode = 'TRADITIONAL';
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'TRADITIONAL';
```